# Squeeze theorem 2 bounded functions

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 \sin (y)}{x^2+y^2} $$

Squeeze Theorem:

$$g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$$

$$-1 \leq \sin(y) \leq 1$$

$$- \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{x^2 \sin (y)}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} $$
Also
$$ 0 \leq \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq 1 $$
What should be my next step
How does this comes out to be zero

Comment: You should have gotten rid of this factor you have at the end instead of getting rid of the $\sin y$

Comment: There exist no limits.

Answer (score 5):

$-1 \leq \sin y \leq 1$ is not helpful in this case.

Use the fact that $|\sin y | \leq |y|$ so $-|y| \leq \sin y \leq |y|$. Now you get the bounds $\pm \frac  {x^{2}|y|} {x^{2}+y^{2}}$. If you note that $\frac  {x^{2}} {x^{2}+y^{2}} \leq 1$ you get $-|y| \leq f(x,y) \leq |y|$ and you can now apply Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use polar coordinates and equivalence of functions:
$$\frac{x^2 \sin (y)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta\sin(r\sin\theta)}{r^2}\sim_{r\to 0}r\sin\theta\cos^2\theta.$$

Comment: Then, no limits

Comment: @haidangel: not at all – $\:r$ tends to $0$ and $\sin\theta\cos^2\theta$ is bounded.

Comment: Its easier to do using polar coordinates but i had to do it using Squeeze theorem which is where i was getting stuck

Comment: @Muskan: In this case, yes. What makes  things still easier (or at least shorter) is also the use of some elementary asymptotic analysis.